# Python repeatedly randomly deleting list entries

Tags: python, list, random, indexing

I am trying to randomly delete a list from a list of lists in Python. It keeps giving me the error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I don't understand how I am referencing somewhere in the list if I am deleting a random integer from 0 -> len(thelist).

I want to randomly delete half of a list (ex/ of 12 members randomly delete 6 of them)

```
for j in range(length/2):
    dynamiclength = len(sorted_population_list)
    del sorted_population_list[random.randint(0, dynamiclength)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) can also return the endpoint value, hence when the returned value is equal to `len(sorted_population_list)` you'll get `IndexError`.

The fix is to use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) which doesn't include the end-point.

Note that for bigger lists it'd be better to create a new list(and re-assign it back to same variable if needed) than using `del` because it is an [`O(N)`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list) operation, so for every deletion you're performing an `O(N)` operation.

Here firstly I am selecting a random sample of size `n` from `xrange` of length equal to list's length, and then using a list comprehension to filter out those indices.

```
def remove_items(lst, n):
    indices = set(random.sample(xrange(len(lst)), n))
    lst[:] = [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i not in indices]
lst = range(12)
remove_items(lst, 4)
print lst  #[1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the simplest fix is a switch to `randrange`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yup! was updating my answer but my connection got yanked.